# Swift + CLLocationManager: How to tell if the user is in a specific city?

Tags: ios

I use CLLocationManager to request the user's location. However, if they are outside of New York City, I want to default to certain coordinates. Is there a way to check if they are in a certain city?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

private let kDefaultLatitude: Double = 40.713
private let kDefaultLongitude: Double = -74.000
private let kDefaultZoomLevel: Float = 16.0

class RootMapViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchLocation()
  }

  private func fetchLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
  }

}

// MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate

extension RootMapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


    let userCoordinates = locations[0].coordinate

    // How do I check if the user is in NYC?

    // if user is in nyc
    centerMapOn(userCoordinates)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    // else default to Times Square
  }

}
```

Comment: such problem I've implemented in such way - every city has central point and radius, and then just compare if userLocation is in radius from central point of the nearest city or not. If you need to implement such problem more detailed you need a polygon with all coordinates, so everything depends on what is your primary task and how accurate it should be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reverse geocoding. For example you can place:

```
geocoder:CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(locations[0],completionHandler{
if error == nil && placemarks.count > 0 {
            let location = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            print(location.locality)

        })
```

in `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`