# Geofencing on iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, location, geofencing

Few months ago, I started to create a dating app.

I used Firebase to store user profiles and preferences, and GeoFire to "detect" when someone enters the radius the user set in his preferences.

Nowadays, GeoFire is no more supported by Firebase 4.0.0, and I would like to know if an alternative exists, or if I can use CoreLocation, and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add geofencing with native framework

Check out this

https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial

Comment: Thanks I will check this out

Comment: I did his tutorial, but I can only know when a user enters or exits a fixed zone on the map, and I can't know if the user is already in the zone because it detect only on the boundaries of the zone

Comment: And I don't know how to get other users location, in other terms, how to make the app search other users in its area, not through all registred locations in the app database

Comment: I didn't tried it , but i also need to implement this .But if you want to try by yourself then pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851046/swift-cllocationmanager-how-to-tell-if-the-user-is-in-a-specific-city

Comment: I found the solution. I installed GeoFire from files, not from Cocoapods, thanks for your help ;)